# Trying to uninstall .Net Core runtimes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I’m needing to remove some .Net Core versions off of some servers. I’m following along with this link but I’m still not sure if I’m actually getting these versions uninstalled.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=windows

If I run `dotnet --list-runtimes` I get a list of .Net Core which include versions below 6.0.10 which I’m trying to get rid of. However, every combination I’ve tried gives me some kind of an issue.

[image]

[image]

What is the best way to determine is a .Net Core version has been fully removed off a server?

Comment: According to the [.NET uninstall tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=windows): _Because of these limitations, the tool might not be able to uninstall all of the .NET SDKs and runtimes on your machine...The `dotnet-core-uninstall list` command displays which SDKs can be uninstalled with the tool. Versions 1.2 and later can uninstall SDKs and runtimes with version 5.0 or earlier, and previous versions of the tool can uninstall 3.1 and earlier_

Comment: Thanks. I did run the uninstall list command, which lead me back to uninstalling the ones it said it could. Those look to be working, although I have to do them individually. What I'm not finding now is how to uninstall a version that can't be uninstalled with the Microsoft Uninstall command.

Comment: Also try: `dotnet-core-uninstall dry-run --runtime --all-below 6.0.311` - a dry run won't remove it, but informs you what would be removed. Notice that you incorrectly specified  `runtimes` instead of `runtime`.

Comment: _What I'm not finding now is how to uninstall a version that can't be uninstalled with the Microsoft Uninstall command_: I would imagine using whatever was used to install it. The uninstaller, Visual Studio Installer, Add/Remove Programs, etc...

Comment: According to the documentation, _You can list several versions one after the other, separated by spaces. Response files are also supported_.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have it all figured out now. I was able to use "Add/Remove Programs" to finish out what I needed.

Comment: In my case, dotnet --list-runtimes would list 5.0.17 runtime, but it was not available in Add/Remove programs, hence "dotnet-core-uninstall remove" was not able to find that version. Running Visual Studio Installer and clicking on "Remove Unsupported Components" helped.